# AWS Code Deploy - Deployed to S3 but not in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

I was trying to deploy my code from BitBucket to EC2. Everything has been setup. I went to click on Deploy to AWS in BitBucket, it shows the following message in AWS:

```
Script does not exist at specified location: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/de9fccf8-b531-4946-bb8e-6bb370e81d09/d-XJMV5YJNV/deployment-archive/after_install.sh
```

I am trying to deploy a NodeJS app. How can I fix this? It has been a day.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment is looking for the file referenced in the error message.  That file is:

```
deployment-archive/after_install.sh
```

Make sure that file exists in the deployment package.

Check the appspec.yml file, found in the root folder of the 
deployment  package. This file specifies the scripts that required during each deployment phase. You should see the above file referenced there.